# On a Gulfstream jet checklist, do you do the walkaround before or after disengaging the gust locks?

Tags: safety, flight-controls, checklist, gulfstream

On a Gulfstream jet checklist, do you do the walkaround before or after disengaging the gust locks?

With small planes we generally remove the gust locks as we do the walk around, but with a larger jet I am wondering what the order of events is. Can you even see if the gust locks are engaged from the exterior of the aircraft or they purely internal and not visible?

Comment: May I suggest checking this item twice.  Relevant [reading](https://news.aviation-safety.net/2017/08/02/faa-ad-gust-lock-modification-gulfstream-g-iv-jets-becomes-effective/).

Answer (score 2):

Since no one is touching this one, an (unqualified) effort may help others to respond.

There are several models of "Gulfstream" jet.  The Gulfstream IV has hydraulicly boosted control surfaces and an internal gust lock release lever in the cockpit.  The system is such that once the engines are started, hydraulic pressure prevents the lock from releasing.  The lock must be released first (check one).

The control surface actuators have a load limit warning light, and stop themselves from bending or tearing the gust lock if it is still applied.
A full control surface movement test - ailerons, rudder, elevator - before roll-out would detect if the gust lock was still engaged (check two).

The gust lock also prevents full application on the throttle (check three).

It would seem to be logical to OFF the gust lock near the top of the very first checklist, and check it again before rolling.